# using sass with compass - 404 css not found

Tags: gruntjs, compass-sass, yeoman

I'm using the followig config for compass with grunt:

```
   compass: {
    options: {
    sassDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
    cssDir: '.tmp/styles',
    imagesDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
    javascriptsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts',
    fontsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/fonts',
    importPath: 'app/components',
    relativeAssets: false
  },
  dist: {},
  server: {
    options: {
      debugInfo: true
    }
  }
},
```

and I see that the sass is getting compiled since it shows in the .tmp/styles folder
but for some reason when I call the css files from the <%= yeoman.app %>/styles filder it's not found

Comment: What do you mean by "when I call the css files from the <%= yeoman.app %>/styles filder it's not found". How do you reference them? What server are you using?

Comment: all the examples online are using connect! I have a strong idea that there is something I an not understanding about nodemon

Comment: If you don't use `grunt server` you have to manually set up the routes so `.tmp/styles/` is picked up.

Comment: I am using grunt server.. how do I manually set up this routes?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know nodemon. I thought that would be an alternative server. What do you use it for?

Comment: it is an alternate server, I use it to run my own node server